# Rails: Upload images and align as a gallery

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I'm uploading images from a rails app I have developed and inside the `edit form` the currently uploaded images appear in one line only: 
[image]

This is the setup I have:

```
 <div class="container-image">
       <% @attachments.each do |attachment| %>
    <div class="item-image">
      <div class="pinImage">
            <%= image_tag(attachment.image.url(:mini))%>
        <p style="font-size: 13px;">
                <%= link_to "Remove", remove_item_attachment_path(attachment),
                            data: { confirm: "Are you sure?"},
                            :method => :delete %></p>
            </div>
          </div>
       <% end %>
      </div>
```

and this is the css:

```
.pinImage img
  width: 100%
  height: auto
  border: 1px solid #d9d9d9
  border-radius: 6px
  background-color: white


.container-image
  max-width: 1200px
  display: flex
  align-items: center
  -webkit-justify-content: center
  /* Safari */
  justify-content: center


.item-image
  padding: 5px
  display: block
```

But I want the images to appear aligned as an image gallery like the following. Any idea how a can fix this?

[image]

Comment: for ".container-image" class use flex-wrap:wrap; it will break your child divs once it will reach the maximum width.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this updated CSS. Added `flex-wrap: wrap;` and removed `justify-content: center` from `container-image` div. Also remove default margins from body.

```css
 
body {
  margin: 0;
}
.pinImage img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  border: 1px solid #d9d9d9;
  border-radius: 6px;
  background-color: white;
}

.container-image{
  max-width: 1200px;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-items: center;
}

.item-image{
display: block;
  width: 25%;
  }
```

```html
 <div class="container-image">
   <div class="item-image">
      <div class="pinImage">
         <img src=""/>
         <p style="font-size: 13px;">
            delete
         </p>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="item-image">
      <div class="pinImage">
         <img src=""/>
         <p style="font-size: 13px;">
            delete
         </p>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="item-image">
      <div class="pinImage">
         <img src=""/>
         <p style="font-size: 13px;">
            delete
         </p>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="item-image">
      <div class="pinImage">
         <img src=""/>
         <p style="font-size: 13px;">
            delete
         </p>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="item-image">
      <div class="pinImage">
         <img src=""/>
         <p style="font-size: 13px;">
            delete
         </p>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="item-image">
      <div class="pinImage">
         <img src=""/>
         <p style="font-size: 13px;">
            delete
         </p>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="item-image">
      <div class="pinImage">
         <img src=""/>
         <p style="font-size: 13px;">
            delete
         </p>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="item-image">
      <div class="pinImage">
         <img src=""/>
         <p style="font-size: 13px;">
            delete
         </p>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="item-image">
      <div class="pinImage">
         <img src=""/>
         <p style="font-size: 13px;">
            delete
         </p>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```